# Normalization of FODE

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have the following first order linear differential equations

$$\dot {z}=z-3t+1$$

$$\dot {t}=z+t-1$$

I have found the unique steady state points as $(z^*,t^*)=(1/2,1/2)$

Now I would like to normalize the system so that the steady-state of the normalized system is at $(0, 0)$.

But I cannot do it properly. Please show me how to solve it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Make a coordinate's change $Z = z-\frac 12, T = t - \frac 12$

Comment: @Cesareo Please can you do it clearly? I just want to learn how to do it. Just for aim of learning.  I will practice your solution way at other questions. Thank you so much.

Comment: After substitution we have $$\cases{\dot Z = Z-3T\\ \dot T = T + Z}$$

Comment: Dear @Cesareo thanks a lot. I understood how to do it. For example, I have the following system, $$\dot{u}=2u-v+5$$ and $$\dot{v}=v-4$$ I have found the steady state points $(u^*,v^*)=(-1/2,4)$. When I normalized the system, $$h=u-u^*$$ and $$w=v-v^*$$then I have obtained the following normalized form $$\dot{h}=2h-w$$ and $$\dot{w}=w$$. Do I understand right? Please take a look. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Now it is OK! You got it!

Comment: Thank you so much dear @Cesareo